# Printing a variable inside a string PHP?

Tags: php, string, url

How would I print $username inside the $url methood ? I just need a quick solution.

```
$username = "gudjondaniel";
$url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/{$username}/uploads?max-results=1';
```

Comment: I removed your "[SOLVED]" from the title.  To make your problem as "solved", check the green checkmark next to the appropriate answer.

Comment: Please use the search before asking a question. I get the feeling you show not reasearch effort what so ever you're asking. Please re-read the guidelines of this website.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best thing to do is URL-encode it and concatenate.

```
$url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/' . urlencode($username) . '/uploads?max-results=1';
```

The concatenate operator `.` sticks strings together into one string.

The `urlencode()` function makes sure any reserved or special characters get encoded properly (such as spaces to `%20`).

Comment: agree, that's the best, concerning this is a url.

Comment: +1 for concat + urlencode()

Answer (score 4):

Use double quotes:

```
$username = "gudjondaniel";
$url    = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/$username/uploads?max-results=1";

echo $url;
```

Comment: Please, don't do this.  It makes reading your code a real hassle.

Comment: I have to say, I TOTALLY agree with you. I guess sometimes I like to feel dirty :)

Comment: Ha, well if you agree, don't respond with such an answer!  This guy doesn't know how to concatenate, so he's new... don't teach bad habits.  Or, at least explain it as such.

Comment: But the code still works perfectly and is perfectly acceptable in some situations. Also he has plenty of answers to chose from. He's learning, let's show him all the ways to do it, and he'll select his style.

Comment: Exactly!  Which is why I made the comment... so he can still see your answer, and realize that it isn't a good way for doing things, and why.

Answer (score 3):

You can concatenate:

```
$username = 'gudjondaniel';
$url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/' . $username . '/uploads?max-results=1';
```

Or use double quotes:

```
    $url = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/$username/uploads?max-results=1";
```